# need to find second largest factor number without using array

Tags: c++

I am finding factor numbers and I do not consider the integer itself as a factor except 1:

```cpp
int factor (int num) {
    int result;
    for (int i = 1; i < num/2; i++) {   
        if (num % i == 0) {
            result = i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Since you're already storing the largest factor, all you need to do is store another value, and copy the previous "largest" into that before setting a new largest.

Comment: Should the `return` statement outside the loop? Also `result` should be initialized to 1, otherwise your code will return uninitialized values when passed `num=1` or `num=2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already mostly complete. You need to take the `return result` after the loop.

```
int factor (int num) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num/2; i++) {   
        if (num % i == 0) {
            result = i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Because you have `i < num/2` you will never have the biggest factor in consideration. It follows the second biggest. That's your return value.

[live test onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/HkvShMzFr)

Answer (score 0):

When you were speaking about factors you probably meant only prime factors.

Second largest can be easily stored without array just by using two variables, `cur` (current) and `prev` (previous), both holding one factor.

You need to do division itself (not only modulus), because if you're just checking `num % i` then you may find non-prime factors too, but you're interested in prime only, that's why you need dividing number `num /= i;`, this will ensure that only prime factors remain. See code below.

Also it is easy to speedup your code very much just by computing factors only till square root of number. It is well known that if we search for divisors smaller than sqrt(num) then remaining divisor will be guaranteed single prime.

Also it is easy to speedup two times more, if you divide only by odd divisors, but for that you need to remove prime 2 from divisors before. I didn't do this optimization only to make code simple, but if you're interested in it please tell in comments.

See examples of output values after the code.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/xe5Ye8GoT)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int factor(int num) {
    int prev = 1, cur = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; ++i)
        while (num % i == 0) {
            prev = cur; cur = i;
            num /= i;
        }
    return num <= 1 ? prev : cur;
}

int main() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << i << " -> " << std::setw(2)
            << factor(i) << ", " << ((i + 1) % 7 == 0 ? "\n" : "");
}
```

Output:

```
  0 ->  1,   1 ->  1,   2 ->  1,   3 ->  1,   4 ->  2,   5 ->  1,   6 ->  2, 
  7 ->  1,   8 ->  2,   9 ->  3,  10 ->  2,  11 ->  1,  12 ->  2,  13 ->  1, 
 14 ->  2,  15 ->  3,  16 ->  2,  17 ->  1,  18 ->  3,  19 ->  1,  20 ->  2, 
 21 ->  3,  22 ->  2,  23 ->  1,  24 ->  2,  25 ->  5,  26 ->  2,  27 ->  3, 
 28 ->  2,  29 ->  1,  30 ->  3,  31 ->  1,  32 ->  2,  33 ->  3,  34 ->  2, 
 35 ->  5,  36 ->  3,  37 ->  1,  38 ->  2,  39 ->  3,  40 ->  2,  41 ->  1, 
 42 ->  3,  43 ->  1,  44 ->  2,  45 ->  3,  46 ->  2,  47 ->  1,  48 ->  2, 
 49 ->  7,  50 ->  5,  51 ->  3,  52 ->  2,  53 ->  1,  54 ->  3,  55 ->  5, 
 56 ->  2,  57 ->  3,  58 ->  2,  59 ->  1,  60 ->  3,  61 ->  1,  62 ->  2, 
 63 ->  3,  64 ->  2,  65 ->  5,  66 ->  3,  67 ->  1,  68 ->  2,  69 ->  3, 
 70 ->  5,  71 ->  1,  72 ->  3,  73 ->  1,  74 ->  2,  75 ->  5,  76 ->  2, 
 77 ->  7,  78 ->  3,  79 ->  1,  80 ->  2,  81 ->  3,  82 ->  2,  83 ->  1, 
 84 ->  3,  85 ->  5,  86 ->  2,  87 ->  3,  88 ->  2,  89 ->  1,  90 ->  3, 
 91 ->  7,  92 ->  2,  93 ->  3,  94 ->  2,  95 ->  5,  96 ->  2,  97 ->  1, 
 98 ->  7,  99 ->  3, 100 ->  5, 101 ->  1, 102 ->  3, 103 ->  1, 104 ->  2, 
105 ->  5, 106 ->  2, 107 ->  1, 108 ->  3, 109 ->  1, 110 ->  5, 111 ->  3, 
112 ->  2, 113 ->  1, 114 ->  3, 115 ->  5, 116 ->  2, 117 ->  3, 118 ->  2, 
119 ->  7, 120 ->  3, 121 -> 11, 122 ->  2, 123 ->  3, 124 ->  2, 125 ->  5, 
126 ->  3, 127 ->  1, 128 ->  2, 129 ->  3, 130 ->  5, 131 ->  1, 132 ->  3, 
133 ->  7, 134 ->  2, 135 ->  3, 136 ->  2, 137 ->  1, 138 ->  3, 139 ->  1, 
140 ->  5, 141 ->  3, 142 ->  2, 143 -> 11, 144 ->  3, 145 ->  5, 146 ->  2, 
147 ->  7, 148 ->  2, 149 ->  1, 150 ->  5, 151 ->  1, 152 ->  2, 153 ->  3, 
154 ->  7, 155 ->  5, 156 ->  3, 157 ->  1, 158 ->  2, 159 ->  3, 160 ->  2, 
161 ->  7, 162 ->  3, 163 ->  1, 164 ->  2, 165 ->  5, 166 ->  2, 167 ->  1, 
168 ->  3, 169 -> 13, 170 ->  5, 171 ->  3, 172 ->  2, 173 ->  1, 174 ->  3, 
175 ->  5, 176 ->  2, 177 ->  3, 178 ->  2, 179 ->  1, 180 ->  3, 181 ->  1, 
182 ->  7, 183 ->  3, 184 ->  2, 185 ->  5, 186 ->  3, 187 -> 11, 188 ->  2, 
189 ->  3, 190 ->  5, 191 ->  1, 192 ->  2, 193 ->  1, 194 ->  2, 195 ->  5, 
196 ->  7, 197 ->  1, 198 ->  3, 199 ->  1,
```